# Parsing JSON objects to post

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, api

I am learning to build a simple API, I have the following code creating the following json:

Code:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' AND post_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR ORDER BY post_date DESC ";
                $result = $dbc->query($sql);

                $rows = array();

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $rows["posts"][$row['post_date']] = $row['post_content'];
                }

                echo json_encode($rows);
```

JSON created:

```
{"posts":{"2015-03-03":"33","2014-03-03":"33 33"}}
```

How do I parse this? I know the following code is a good start, but have not been able to go anywhere from there with success:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost:8888/290_project/api_write.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success : function(data){

        }
});
```

Maybe I should then do something like in this w3 schools example?

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
```

I have yet to have luck thus far with this though, but I know I am so close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a clearer interface to interact with, you may consider changing your script to return data in a form that is easier to work with:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $post = array();
    $post['date'] = $row['post_date'];
    $post['content'] = $row['post_content'];

    $rows["posts"][] = $post;
}
```

In your success function, you have access to the data as a javascript object

```
success : function(data){
  alert(data.posts[0].date);
  alert(data.posts[0].content);
}
```

You can manipulate this data here any way you like without parsing it.

Comment: this gives me [object Object], and if I run: alert(data.posts[0]); I expect "2015-03-03" but get undefined. How exactly would I manipulate from there to get what I want? This is where I keep hitting a road block.

Comment: 'posts' is not an array so posts[0] will return undefined. Perhaps you actually want your PHP script to return a JSON array as the value for posts: `{"posts":[{"date" : "2015-03-03", "post_content" : "33"},{"date" : "2014-03-03", "post_content" : "33 33"}]}`. Then you can access each post like `data.posts[0].date` etc.

Comment: So I would need to restructure: $rows["posts"][$row['post_date']] = $row['post_content']; ?

Comment: $rows["posts"]["date"][$row['post_date']] = $row['post_content']; this seems like the right direction, but I am not getting what I need.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been working on this for days, much learned!

Answer (score 1):

I think `$.parseJSON` is your solution. You can do this in your success event:

```
$.ajax({
url : "http://localhost:8888/290_project/api_write.php",
dataType: 'json',
type: 'get',
cache: false,
success : function(data){
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data);

    }
});
```

Comment: Seems like it should work but I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't even need to parse it if you use

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8888/290_project/api_write.php', function(alreadyParsedJsonData) {
  // do stuff
});
```